# Intra-word bolding renders differently in preview than in actual posts

Tags: bug, markdown-preview

Consider the following markdown:

```
ab**cd**ef

あい**う**えお

அஆ**இஈ**உஊ
```

Here is the same markdown without four leading spaces:

ab**cd**ef

あい**う**えお

அஆ**இஈ**உஊ

Here is what this looks like (at the time of writing), in preview (e.g. when editing a question, writing a new answer, etc):

[image: preview]

Here is what this looks like (at the time of writing), in actual questions and answers:

[image: actual]

There is a clear inconsistency between what appears in the markdown preview and what actually appears in the question, but only for some strings of characters. This is a mild annoyance over at Japanese.SE (and possibly elsewhere), where this sort of bolding is often desired (yes, I'm aware that you can work around it by using `<b>...</b>` or wrapping the `**...**` in zero-width spaces, but people generally don't expect to have to do that).

To clarify, I'm not saying that intra-word `**...**` should produce bolding; I'm saying that the markdown preview should reflect the fact that intra-word `**...**` *doesn't* produce bolding.